# creating my own user entity

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, jhipster

I wish to make my own **' user '** entity to log in the application.

what I want to know is that if it's possible and if it is possible then where should I take precaution, which points should I consider and which files I would need to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a userclass by implementing UserDetailsService like

```
  @Transactional
 @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
   throws UsernameNotFoundException {

  MyUser details = userDao.getUser(username);
  Collection<simplegrantedauthority> authorities = new ArrayList<simplegrantedauthority>();
  SimpleGrantedAuthority userAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
    "ROLE_USER");
  SimpleGrantedAuthority adminAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
    "ROLE_ADMIN");
  if (details.getRole().equals("user"))
   authorities.add(userAuthority);
  else if (details.getRole().equals("admin")) {
   authorities.add(userAuthority);
   authorities.add(adminAuthority);
  }
  UserDetails user = new User(details.getUsername(),
    details.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
  return user;
 }
}
```

an then configure spring to use your customuser object... like

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authService">
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```

Full example can be found at [Spring Custom User with DAO and Entity](http://technirman.blogspot.in/2013/12/spring-security-custom-userdetails.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a user service extending UserDetailsService, and then create your UserDetail object.

It would be similar to this.

Create you User class:

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private UserEntity user;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    /**
     * Constructor 
     */
    public MyUserDetails(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getAuthorities()
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getPassword()
     */
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getUsername()
     */
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonExpired()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonLocked()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !user.isLocked();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isCredentialsNonExpired()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return !user.isExpired();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isEnabled()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }

    /**
     * @return the user
     */
    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * @param user the user to set
     */
    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Then you should create your UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
   */
    @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user = userDao.findByEmail(username);

        if (user == null) {
                LOGGER.warn("User {} does not exist in our database", username);
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
        }

        return new MyUserDetails(user);
  }
}
```

And finally you should add the configuration for Spring security to use your service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```